# asynchronousRulesetParsing XU property and the Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

My ruleset is deployed on the Business Rules service on Bluemix, and I want to execute an older version of a ruleset while the newer one is being parsed. To do so, I am trying to configure the XU property asynchronousRulesetParsing, but I cannot figure out how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XU properties cannot be configured for the Business Rules service on Bluemix.

Specifically regarding the asynchronousRulesetParsing XU property, I found that it is not applicable when using Hosted Transparent Decision Services (HTDS) in ODM, since the implementation of HTDS always forces the latest version of rulesets to be used.

Since the Business Rules service on Bluemix uses HTDS, the asynchronousRulesetParsing XU property is also not applicable.

Instead, once I deploy a new ruleset version, I send a "dummy" request to force the parsing of the new ruleset version and incur the parsing delay. I wait for this request to complete before running the "real" requests of the ruleset.